# gcc works well with lex, but cannot find a libl.so on hard disk

Tags: gcc, hyperlink, lex

I can work using lex like below:

> lex my.l && gcc lex.yy.c -ll

No problem, it works. From gcc link option, I guess there's a library named libl.so which indicates lex runtime library.

```
cd /
find ./ -name "libl.so"
```

But I don't get any find result. So is there really a library called libl.so? What's the realy library name used by gcc to link with lex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how you installed (f)lex; the library might be an archive rather than a shared object (i.e. `libl.a`). Flex usually also provides `libfl.a` and `libfl.so`

If you have a debian or ubuntu system, the (f)lex libraries are in the `libfl-dev` package, which (on an x86_64 platform) includes the following libraries:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfl.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfl_pic.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfl.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libl.a
```

as well as some other files.

Answer (score 4):

For RHEL or Centos, you need to install flex-devel to get the libfl.a and libl.a and bison-devel to get liby.a.